# How to pass the parameters correctly into FluentHelper's select method

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I'm getting the columns on which select parameter is applied.

```
String selectParams = context.getParameterInfo().getQueryParameter("$select"); 
Object[] param = selectParams.split(",");
```

Now I need to pass these fields on which $select must be applied to FluentHelper's select method. It accepts arguments of type SelectableT.

```
public FluentHelperT select( @Nonnull final SelectableT... fields )
{
    final Iterable<EntitySelectable<?>> selectableFields = (Iterable<EntitySelectable<?>>) Arrays.asList(fields);
    return super.select(selectableFields, delegateQuery::select, delegateQuery::select);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

TIA.

Comment: Can you please update the question with more details? Which version of SAP Cloud SDK are you using? How are you obtaining the parameters to be selected? Have you generated a VDM to to access the service?  Here is an example of select's [usage](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/use-typed-odata-v2-client-in-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#select)

Comment: Cloud SDK's version is 3.48.0. I'm getting the columns to be selected from the CdsReadEventContext. I've mentioned this in the question as well. Yes, I've generated the VDM to access the service. The problem is that how do I send the fields in a correct way to the helper.select(<parameter>) method, which takes parameter of type SelectableT.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a lambda expression to FluentHelper's select method.
For e.g.

```java
String selectParams = context.getParameterInfo().getQueryParameter("$select"); 
Object[] param = selectParams.split(",");

//Please use your relevant service and it's fluent helper here
fluentHelper = service.getAll...(); //

for(Object param:params){
   fluentHelper.select(()->param.toString());
}
//Now continue with executing your request
fluenHelper.executeRequest(destination);
```